# Binding TextBlock To Observable Collection

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, textblock

I am trying to bind a textblock to a item in a observable collection.  Below is the class and the property for the collection.  Am I binding correctly?  Thanks!

```
public class ListStuff
{
  public string Name { get; set;}
}

private ObservableCollection<ListStuff> mListStuff = new ObservableCollection<ListStuff>();

public ObservableCollection<ListStuff> NameLists
        {
            get
            {
                return mListStuff;
            }
        }
```

Here is the Xaml if I bind to NameLists it says (collection)

```
        <Border Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" BorderThickness="0"                        
            <TextBlock Margin="0,5" FontSize="24" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Text="{Binding Path=Name"}/>                                                                        
          </Border>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your "Name" property has to be public. You can bind only against public properties. Leaving out identifier from property name, means essentially that it becomes a private one, so WPF system can't find it, because it searches only for public properties using reflection.

Comment: You are not giving enough information, your Xaml has serious typos(atleast I hope so). Why don't you paste the code you're actually using? You need to bind against NameLists property using some kind of container(ItemsControl, ComboBox, TabControl, etc..)

Comment: Thanks Erti    this link was helpful after reading your suggestions http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/09/17/wpf-itemscontrol-example/